# Selenium, For loop: how to make a loop last when there is no specific element on the page

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have a script that looks for certain sources from the page. Sometimes, however, there are no sources at all and the loop stops working. I have no idea how to solve this problem because I have already specified where the script should look for the elements.

```
servers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="links- 
container"]/div[2]').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

When there are no sources, the page does not have an html object such as when these elements exist. This could be added for an exception.

```
no_elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]')
```

But I don't really know where to add it. Below is the scrape of my code.

```
srcs = []

servers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="links- 
container"]/div[2]').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for server in servers:
try:

    txt = server.get_attribute('textContent').lower()

    link_type = txt.split()[2]

    if txt.find('test') >= 0:
        button = server.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button)

        tm=0
        while(True):
            try:


                browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])


                srcs.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/div/iframe').get_attribute('src') + "@" + link_type)

                browser.close()
                browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

                break
            except:
                if tm==5:break
                tm+=1

except Exception as e:
    print (str)(e)
    continue
```

So basically the script is looking for specific links and clicks on it, open in new tab, gets src and returns for next one.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Edit your code as the indentation is obviously broken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python + Selenium: Wait until element is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded)

Comment: Instead of clicking each link, switching tabs, and then getting the URL... why don't you just get the URL from href in the A tag on the original page. Your script would run lightning fast. One issue might be if clicking the link resulted in a redirect the URL you gather wouldn't be the same as the final redirect.

Comment: @JeffC Well, I need to open the link to get src from video player attached to page, I didn't describe it precisely but you can see in the code.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?